# How to make a webview is -10dp width and height of the parent layout?

Tags: android, layout, webview

How to make a webview is -10dp width and height of the parent layout with a background image look like the  following image:

Updated:
The blue box is the screen. 
The black box is the outer layout(@+id/wrapper) and the red box is the webview(@+id/webview)
The green box is some other layout.

[image: demo]

I have tried with the following code but have no success.
If the content in the webview is too long, the outer layout will stretch. I want a fixed size webview inside the layout but I don't know how to achieve this.

Ps. The background image of the black box is not full screen.

Would somebody give me some hints?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/common_background" >

    ... some other layout ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/wrapper_background" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ... some other layout ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just update android:layout_height="match_parent" into xml file

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/someOtherLayout"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/wrapper_background" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<Some Other Layout
    android:id="@+id/someOtherLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please see the image. The background image of black box is not full screen.

Comment: @Hanon Check my updated answer, and if it dosent work still, then please provide complete source code of your xml, and please stop referring your views as black box, green box, red box, etc. Its very confusing. Instead use the ids of each views.

Answer (score 0):

use

> android:padding="10dip" to the parent of webview.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead

it will look like As shown in image
[image]

xml Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >


  ... some other layout ...
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  ... some other layout ...


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please see the image. The background image of black box is not full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wrapper_background" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>      android:layout_width="match_parent"
>      android:layout_height="match_parent"
>      android:background="@drawable/common_background" >
> ... some other layout ...
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/wrapper"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>     android:padding="10dip"                   <---- Apply this in your layout.
>     android:background="@drawable/wrapper_background" >
>     <WebView
>         android:id="@+id/webview"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>          />
>   </LinearLayout>
>    ... some other layout ...
>   </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: I have updated my question, please see the image. The background image of black box is not full screen. I've tried this solution but it still stretch.